# Pandas Multiple condition on column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
Column A      Column B
1              10
1              10
0              10
0              10
3              20
```

I have to check if column A is 0 and column B is 10 then change column A to 1

```
df.loc[(df['Column A']==0) & (df['Column B'] == 10) ,df['Column A']] = 1
```

But i am getting an error
Final df should look something like this None of [Int64Index([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,\n            ...\n            1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1],\n           dtype='int64', length=2715)] are in the [columns]"

I think my solution is not correct. All the indexes are correct

```
Column A      Column B
1              10
1              10
1              10
1              10
3              20
```

Comment: Try `df.loc[(df['Column A']==0) & (df['Column B'] == 10) ,'Column A'] = 1`.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang It worked !!

Comment: Not a `numpy` or `scikit-learn` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).